# An interpretation of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, applications

Suppose we have an Stieltjes integral $h=\int f dg$ then use the fundamental theorem to get $dh=fdg$ and divide by $dg$ i.e $\frac{dh}{dg}=f$.

Is this meaningful and if so does anyone know any situation/application where this occurs?

Comment: It is meaningful, have a look at Radon-Nikodym derivates (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seperation of variables is a textbook example!